# What is the best way to convert Trello boards/lists/cards to OneNote notebooks/sections/pages, respectively?

Tags: trello, onenote

Basically, I need to transfer **a lot of** info from Trello to OneNote. Can't waste time doing it manually.
There is some info on the JSON export from Trello [here](http://help.trello.com/article/924-making-sense-of-trellos-json-export), but it is unclear how to import JSON to OneNote.